# Unable to connect to the remote server error while running same windows service with 4 instances

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have created a windows service in C#. I would like to configure same service for 4 different databases & want to run at the same time.
In order to do I have create 4 different setup projects & building with different assembly name of Service Project but it gives me Unable to connect remote server error.

```
Unable to connect to the remote server
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpWebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at MyService.CRMService1.CrmService.RetrieveMultiple(QueryBase query)
   at TitaniumService.clsCRM.loadEntityByAttributeValue(CrmService crmService, String EntityTypeName, String AttributeName1, Object AttributeValue1, String AttributeName2, Object AttributeValue2)
   at MyService.clsCRM.Product(CrmService service, Double price, String ProductNumber, String UM)
   at MyService.MyThread.UpdateProduct(clsCRM objCRM, CrmService objService, String RefID, String Product_pfx, String SO_Guid, Double SO_totalAmount, String CompanyID)
```

Also I have run this service only for single instance that is running perfect without giving the above error message.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Most likely this is because your remote server isn't accessible.  Can you successfully make the single instance that *is* working connect to the same server/database as the one that is failling?

Comment: Yes I have done so as well. & it was working with single instance.